# Kafka Streams - How to match 2 relevant messages to generate another message

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to implement a Kafka stream which processes website visit messages (`PageEntered` and `PageLeft`) and generate another message (`PageVisited`).

The input event is as follows:

```
case class WebsiteEvent(session: String, time: Long, event: Action)
sealed trait Action {
  def url: String
}
final case class PageEntered(url: String) extends Action
final case class PageLeft(url: String) extends Action
```

and the output is:

```
case class PageVisited(session: String, url: String, duration: Long)
```

I grouped by the session and url, but couldn't figure out how to match the PageEntered and PageLeft events.

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder
val stream = builder.stream[String, WebsiteEvent]("website-events-topic")
                    .groupBy((_, event) => event.session -> event.action.url)
                    ... // stuck here
                    .map{ case ((session, url), (entered, left)) =>
                      PageVisited(session, url, left.time - entered.time)
                    }
                    .to("page-visited-topic")
```

As I'm new to Kafka-Streams, I was wondering if I'm heading in the right direction and how I could achieve it.

P.S. I have no control over the input structure.